# how to enable and disable radio buttons to checkboxes with JQ

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I need to disable and enable 3 radio button with a checkbox starting from this switch

```
jQuery("input:checked").each(function () {
        var valore = jQuery(this).val();
        if(str != ""){
            str += " + ";
        }
        switch(valore)
                {
                    case "1": 
                       str += "casa";
                       if(num == "") num = "cooc &euro;";                                            
                    break;
                    case "2": 
                       str += "Struttura";
                       if(num == "") num = "cccd";
                    break;
                    case "3": 
                       str += "inserzione";
                       if(num == "") num = "ddds;";
                    break;
                    default:;
                }
```

Html

```
<input id="radio-01" value="3" name="radio" type="radio" class="rambo" />
<input id="radio-01" value="3" name="radio" type="radio" class="rambo" />
<input id="radio-01" value="3" name="radio" type="radio" class="rambo" />
<input id="radio-01" value="3" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" class="rambo" />
```

Help me 
Thanks for advice

Comment: If you assign an Id to any objects then make sure that all IDs are unique within your current page.

Answer (score 0):

Love the class name.

You should use `$('input [type="radio"]).attr('checked', true)` inside your switch if you want to check all 3 radios.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="radio"]').attr('disabled', true);
```